# Set struts2 jquery grid column names from strust2 action class dynamically

Tags: json, struts2, jqgrid

I am using strust2 jquery grid. My problem is my grid column names directly come from strust2 action class or DAO class. The grid dynamically form based on DAO class.so properties of DAO class dynamically set to grid column names.

```
 function sample()
 {
      $("#reloadgrid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{ datatype: 'json',page:1});
      $.publish('reloadgrid1');
      return false; 
 }
$.subscribe('reloadgrid1', function(event,element) 
{

var selRowIds=new Array();
var id=new Array();
var disc=new Array();
var data=new Array();
var ret=new Array();
var selRowIds=$('#reloadgrid').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
if(selRowIds.length<=selRowIds.length)
{
for( var i=0;i<selRowIds.length;i++){
        ret[i] = $("#reloadgrid").jqGrid('getRowData',selRowIds[i]); 
       id[i]=ret[i].id;
       disc[i]=ret[i].disc;
       data[i]=ret[i].data;
     if(disc[i]==null||data[i]==null||disc[i]==""||data[i]=="")
     {
         alert("Please enter values into grid");
        return false;
     }       
}
} 
     var totrec=$('#reloadgrid').jqGrid('getGridParam','reccount');
  //    alert(totrec);
        $("#reloadgrid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{ datatype: 'json'});
        $("#reloadgrid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{ postData:
                                                {
                                                 id:id,
                                                 disc:disc,
                                                 data:data,
                                                 reccount:totrec},
                                                 url: "finalAction"
                                                }).trigger('reloadGrid');

    });
   $.subscribe('rowselect', function(event, data)
    {

        var id=event.originalEvent.id;
        alert(id);
        var gr = $("#reloadgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');

         if(gr)
        {
         $('#reloadgrid').jqGrid('editRow',gr,true);

         }
    });
       function formatLink(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return "<input type='button' value='save' onClick='return saverow()'>                    
       <input type='button' value='delete' onClick='return deleterow()'>";
  }
  function saverow()
  {
var gr = $("#reloadgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
if(gr!=null)
{   
$('#reloadgrid').jqGrid('saveRow',gr);
return true;
}
else
{    
return false;
} 
return false;
 }
    function deleterow()
  {
alert("Confirm deletion");
var gr = $("#reloadgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    if(gr!=null)
   {    
     $("#reloadgrid").jqGrid('delGridRow',gr);
   }

   }

 </script>


 <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS',verdana;">


 <s:actionerror></s:actionerror>

  <s:form id="simpleForm" action="finalAction">
  <s:url var="gridid" action="gridAction" >
   </s:url>   
  <s:url var="editid" action="EditAction"/>
    <s:url var="finalid" action="finalAction"/>
  </s:form>

    <sjg:grid gridModel="gridmodelsample"
      id="reloadgrid"
      dataType="json"
      loadonce="true"
      href="%{gridid}"
      rowNum="3"
      gridview="true"
      width="600"
      viewrecords="true"
      editinline="true"
      editurl="%{editid}"
      navigator="false"
      navigatorEdit="false"
      navigatorView="false"
      navigatorAdd="false"
      onSelectRowTopics="rowselect"
      navigatorDelete="false"
      navigatorInlineEditButtons="true"
      caption="jQuery Inline Editing Grid"
      pager="true"
      multiselect="false"
      rowList="5,10,15,20"
      reloadTopics="reloadgrid"
      onGridCompleteTopics="createbuttons">
     <sjg:gridColumn name="editoperation" title="" formatter="formatLink">               </sjg:gridColumn>

</sjg:grid>

<sj:submit button="true" name="save" onClick="return sample()" value="save"/>

  </body>
</html>
```

My problem is that the grid column names dynamically come from action class and set to grid column headers or titles.

Comment: name coming dynamically is your problem or what?

Comment: The action class properties not come to my jsp and it is not able to set as grid column names and titles..Action class properties are set to my grid column titles.

Comment: @user1384087 were you able to solve it?

Comment: solve it through create another action class for titles and the json result getting dynamically when grid is load.